# Number of items specifying image in Adaptive Cards

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to design an adaptive card, but I'm stuck at a point. Like if an order has multiple items, how can I show it in the same way as the attached image shows? Can someone help me out with this. Thanks in Advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWtQk.jpg)

Comment: You are trying on SDK or composer?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I'm using SDK

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Hi, Farid, I just wanted to know, is there any update from your side? Sorry if I'm rude.

Comment: Not really, I haven't tried that, busy with other stuff. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @LalithadityaKota I don't think we can populate multiple orders under a single order with "+2" but you could try using a carousel for the same.

Comment: @ElmaSarahDaniel Thanks for your reply. Yes, I displaying the orders using carousel, like some stores have a order in which we have two or more items. My question was to generate a image for an order, where the order has two or more items.